# Is an answer that just confirms another answer allowed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, review-audits

During review, I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23619656/1877903). I thought it appropriate to flag as "not an answer", but it turned out to be one of those review audits and apparently, it is considered a high quality answer.

I understand it is fairly comprehensive, but basically, this answer just confirms that the answer of another user is correct. Is that allowed? Should it be allowed?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer. One could argue this should have been an edit to that other answer, or a comment.

Comment: @kapa, I agree that this answer is useful. My point is that I don't actually think this is a proper answer to the question. My question is where do we draw a line if any on what actually constitutes an answer? Comments on other answers should obviously not be answers, when is it a comment and when is it something more?

Comment: It is not exactly just confirming the correctness. It is giving evidence that it is correct and explaining the evidence. I don't see anything particularly wrong with that, personally. At any rate, I don't think it qualifies as "does not attempt to answer the question"

Comment: Those answers are grabbing for the low-hanging fruit by taking an elaborate and useful answer given by a third user and turning it into a "copy this code" answer in the hopes of OP awarding them with the solved tag.

Comment: I would say that if you can remove "@Praetorian's answer is correct." part from such answer and it will not be duplicate answer and still will answer the question then there is no problem with it.

Comment: @Pshemo IMO your comment is the only thing that actually should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @hvd I don't mind if you create answer which starts with "Pshemo's comment is correct" :)

Comment: I got this same audit a week ago, and [also failed it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4910064) for the same reason.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An answer is just something that

1. Answers the question

...

That's it.

Now, obviously we hold answers to higher standards than that. For boolean questions we still want explanations. When the answer is uncertain, educated guesses are fine *as long as they are evidenced*. But more explanation and divulging into the answer is appreciated.

So what standards count as reasonable? I propose just one:

> It needs to contribute to mission of Stack Overflow as a site for high quality questions and answers.

This *definitely* did that. It answered the question. It improved understanding. It increased certainty of the answer. What more do you want?

**Summary**

The fact that someone else guessed the answer beforehand with a reasonable and well-explained hypothesis doesn't mean that the answer is less good. If the answer replaced the part that goes

> @Praetorian's answer is correct.

with just

> Yes.

you would have never have brought this up because *it **is** a good answer*.

Comment: Actually he would have, since if it started with Yes, the rest of the answer would make no sense, it just explains why the other answer is good, it doesn't answer the question at all!

Comment: "Yes" would answer "Is this valid C++11 (or C++14)?" The part at the end going "as you can see it ...", as well as the given code, answers "What does it mean?"

Comment: When you review, you don't actually see the other answers. One problem is that, without the context of the other answer, there is no way of determining if this is just a repetition or not. IMHO an answer should be able to stand by itself without needing someone to take other answers into consideration. Other than that personal gripe, I agree with your point and on closer inspection, it does at least "Answer the question" so "Not an answer" is certainly not appropriate

Comment: I would see it more appropriate as a comment to the first answer pointing out the source code rather than another answer. Those are fairly old, doubt that anything will change. The answer shouldn't be used as audit... another reason to always open in another tab while reviewing

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau "The answer shouldn't be used as audit" -- On the other hand, the tricky edge-case ones are what teach reviewers the most. That's exactly *why* it should be an audit (although it could also come with explanatory text).

Comment: I understand your point and agree but audits are [really to catch robo-reviewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/227881) and shouldn't be tricky edge-cases.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I remember a recent "dispute" involving a mod purposefully adding a trickier audit, which seems to contradict that. I'll try and find it. Maybe it'll make an interesting Meta question...

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau FWIW, I didn't find the "dispute".

Comment: @Veedrac: I would not qualify it as "a good answer". It basically dumps the involved code with little to no explanation. It is an answer though, which is sufficient I guess.

Comment: @neelsg The text "@Praetorian's answer" is basically giving you context as to what the answer refers to. I've also seen answers refer to comments to the question. Some people are just polite that way, being trained by years of college education and/or writing papers to always cite sources to avoid plagiarism. If I were to review this I'd right click on the question and find out what "@Praetorian's answer" is. The primary utility of this site is for the users, not reviewers. And users googling for solutions would certainly appreciate knowing the answer expands on another answer (I would)

Answer (score 32):

If it *just* confirms another answer is correct, then no, it's not allowed. If the entire body of that answer had been:

> @Praetorian's answer is correct.

then it's obviously "not an answer". Even as a comment on the answer that would be pretty useless.

However, in this specific case there's a whole lot more in that answer that *might* make it a satisfactory answer to the question on its own merits, even if it begins by confirming that another answer is correct. I don't have enough knowledge of the topic to judge that, and those handling flags aren't expected to have that knowledge either, so flagging as "not an answer" isn't appropriate.

Comment: "and those handling flags aren't expected to have that knowledge either" -- Strongly disagree. If it's not an answer, it's not an answer. If someone doesn't have enough knowledge of the subject to determine whether the flag is appropriate, just skip the flag and leave it for someone else. Your suggestion would effectively mean that "not an answer" is *never* a meaningful flag for anything other than the major tags on SO.

Comment: @hvd "Not an answer" doesn't mean "this is wrong" or "this uses bad reasoning". It means "this *doesn't attempt* to answer the question". It's mostly (but not exclusively) for things like "me too!" or "thanks" or "here's an edit to the question", and only maybe *rarely* for "here's the answer to a different question".

Comment: @Veedrac That answer doesn't attempt to answer the question, it only validates the other answer by pointing out that it is correct from the code pasted.

Comment: @Veedrac If a C question asks "how do I read a number from standard input", and an answer states "use the getNumber function" (even though no such function exists), I do expect it to be deleted as not an answer. Am I correct in understanding that you think it shouldn't be deleted, just downvoted?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259890/is-an-answer-that-just-confirms-another-answer-allowed/259936#comment39552_259938

Comment: @hvd Yes. I do think that. It's not for the mods to decide what's *right*, just for them to decide what's *on topic*. The voters get to say what's right.

Comment: @Veedrac Alright, fair enough. Looking for confirmation (one way or another), I found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used), which does agree with you. I do think this is a very bad idea, and I do regularly see such answers deleted, though.

Answer (score 19):

Anthony's answer is correct.

> Such answers are comments, and should be flagged.

Comment: I do see what you did there, but that's not what Anthony's answer says.

Comment: Sorry, just had to take the appropriate action :)

Answer (score 8):

Pshemo is correct.

If you omit the "@Praetorian's answer is correct." from the answer, you still have something that answers the question, and manages to do so without being just a copy of Praetorian's answer, or anyone else's. That makes it something that shouldn't be flagged "not an answer".

Admittedly, if you remove the reference to Praetorian's answer, it does become a bit cryptic, but it still addresses the question.

Comment: He's right but you're wrong, the answer is only validating the other ones, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It does, take a look at the last two sentences: "as you can see it overloaded free function operator->* which takes a signal (D::MakeVar(0)) and a functor (lambda) and free function operator, which takes two signal" That is a correct answer to the question. It's not as clear as Praetorian's, though.